# using someone else's wordlist in a published iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm in the process of writing a program that requires a long list of words to function. I have one on my computer, but I don't remember its source, and I was only using it to learn, so I paid no attention to where I got it. But now that I'm seriously considering writing and publishing this `iOS` app (eventually), I get the feeling that whoever made this list would not be happy if I made profit or even published something that contains their own work. Do you know of any word lists in .txt format that I could use for publishing a possibly paid `iOS` app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "open source word lists".  Some examples include [Kevin's Word List](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net) and [The English Open Word List](http://dreamsteep.com/projects/the-english-open-word-list.html)